# swfupload image resize halting if the image dimensions are large?

Tags: swfupload

I'm using swfupload to upload pictures and resize them at client side. For testing purposes, I created a png that is 5000x5000 and has a very small size and image resize is failing on it. Anybody faced any image resizing issues when dimensions are too large? using swfupload?

I have included the debug log: For two files - one that went successfully and the other one that halted.

```
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogStart : Browsing files. Single Select. Allowed file types: *.jpg; *.png
SWF DEBUG: Select Handler: Received the files selected from the dialog. Processing the file list...
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileQueued : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogComplete : Finished processing selected files. Files selected: 1. Files Queued: 1
SWF DEBUG: StartUpload: First file in queue
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadStart : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: StartUpload(): Uploading Type: Resized Image.
SWF DEBUG: PrepareThumbnail(): Beginning image resizing.
SWF DEBUG: Settings: Width: 250, Height: 250, Encoding: JPEG, Quality: 100.
SWF DEBUG: PrepareResizedImageCompleteHandler(): Finished resizing. Initializing MultipartURLLoader.
SWF DEBUG: ReturnUploadStart(): File accepted by startUpload event and readied for resized upload.  Starting upload to /FileUpload/AsyncUpload for File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress (OPEN): File ID: SWFUpload_0_0 Bytes: 0. Total: 36585
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress (simulated 100%): File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 36585. Total: 36585
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadSuccess: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0 Response Received: true Data: {"guid":"04cbb2ca-f7a2-4f75-9c14-b8e19e5ca9b2.jpg","width":250,"height":190}
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadComplete : Upload cycle complete.
```

The file that halted:

```
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogStart : Browsing files. Single Select. Allowed file types: *.jpg; *.png
SWF DEBUG: Select Handler: Received the files selected from the dialog. Processing the file list...
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileQueued : File ID: SWFUpload_0_1
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogComplete : Finished processing selected files. Files selected: 1. Files Queued: 1
SWF DEBUG: StartUpload: First file in queue
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadStart : File ID: SWFUpload_0_1
SWF DEBUG: StartUpload(): Uploading Type: Resized Image.
SWF DEBUG: PrepareThumbnail(): Beginning image resizing.
SWF DEBUG: Settings: Width: 250, Height: 250, Encoding: JPEG, Quality: 100.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Player 10 applies limitation to maximum image size. BitmapData object  can have maximum 8191 pixels width or height, and total number of pixels cannot exceed 16777215. Larger images cannot be loaded in Flash 10.